# Measuring the capacity of a capacitor with arduino?

Tags: arduino, capacitor

I'm preparing for a little Arduino project that our teacher announced that will most likely be a discharge voltage measurement of a capacitor with some curve fitting in Excel. So my goal is get the exponential curve in Excel, but I don't see how I can do that.

My idea was to charge the capacitor with a battery or whatever, and then plug in the capacitor into the GND and an analog input (A0) and read the digital value with some code.

Can anyone explain the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Are you familiar with the RC time constant?

Comment: I was told that `tau = R * C`, without understanding what the benefit is of that.

Comment: Since you will use a known resistor value the problem boils down to finding \$\tau\$ by fitting a voltage vs time sample set to an exponential ideal curve. What part of that is a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the Arduino's analog inputs to take measurements.  The impedance of the ADC input should be large enough so it will not affect your measurements.

Depending on the X-axis (time scale) of your spreadsheet, you will want to take readings at a fixed rate, say every 10 ms or whatever you choose.  Then save the values to RAM.

Connect the Arduino to a PC using a USB to UART bridge [like this one from SparkFun](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9718).  The UART will show up as a virtual COMM port on the PC.

Download a terminal program like [RealTerm](http://realterm.sourceforge.net/), and open it to the port indicated in the Device Manager of your PC corresponding to the virtual COMM port of USB cable.

In the Arduino, convert each reading to an ASCII number followed by a carriage return/line feed (cr/lf), and output to the UART.  When done copy the readings from the terminal program and input them to Excel.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer. However, I'm not even sure how to connect the capacitor to the arduino. Do I need a resistor? My first guess would have been to connect one cable from `GND`to the capacitor, the other end of the capacitor to the analog input `A0`.